# create a Sprite list from a tmx map (TiledMap) in LibGdx

Tags: java, libgdx, sprite, tiled, tmx

After many search on the internet I cannot find the answer ..

**What is the situation ?**
I'm a student in computer science at university (in belgium) and i have to make a tower defense in Java with the graphic library LibGdx.

**What is the problem ?** 
In LibGdx, there is a map object named "TiledMap". It allows to load a tmx map (made with tiled for example..) 
So i load this map with this code :

```
TiledMap tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader().load(name);
```

And i render it with this code :

```
TiledMapRenderer tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap);
OrthographicCamera camera = new OrthographicCamera(960, 900); // Size of map
camera.position.set(posX, posY, 0);
camera.update();
tiledMapRenderer.setView(camera);
tiledMapRenderer.render();
```

But i don't found a method or something that allows me to separate the tmx map on a list of Sprite.. like

"private Sprite[][] tiles" .. this attribute will allow to change a tile at the position (0,0) by the sprite of a tower (if the player wants to build a tower to this position)

and also with properties used to make the tmx map i'll able to do another attribute like

"private boolean[][] isWay" .. to know if the tile (0,0) is the way (monsters can walk only if the tile is way)..

**So i don't know how to change the TiledMap to Sprite[][]**

I'm sorry if i do some english mistakes but i try to improve my english everyday...

Thank you for your help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TiledMap doesn't have any Sprite instances. You can get refererence to a TiledMapTileLayer via `TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(0)` which would get the first layer.

With that, you can get and set the cells (and the tiles they contain) via `layer.getCell(x, y)` and `layer.setCell(x, y, cell)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! 

With layer.getCell(x,y) it'll be possible to work with Sprite ?

Comment: No, you'd be working with instances of TiledMapTile - StaticTiledMapTile is a normal tile, AnimatedTiledMapTile takes a list of static tiles and animates them.

Comment: Ok and last question.. the cell (0;0) is always at the corner bottom left or it's possible to change that ?

Comment: no, but you can create a method that inverts the position 0,0 to maxwidth,maxheight and use as you please.